# Wakes from suspend immediately when bluetooth device disconnected

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, suspend, bluetooth

When I suspend my Dell XPS 13 9379, `NetworkManager` wakes it again immediately if my bluetooth mouse is not connected:

```
# journalctl -ex
...
systemd-logind[653]: Operation 'sleep' finished.
NetworkManager[650]: <info>  [1541032616.6736] manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
NetworkManager[650]: <info>  [1541032616.6739] device (enxa0cec8126450): state change: unavailable -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
NetworkManager[650]: <info>  [1541032616.7017] device (enxa0cec8126450): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
...
```

How can I prevent Bluetooth from waking my machine?

---

Apparently Bluetooth is either irrelevant or not the only source of the issue, as my machine woke (or rather, failed to sleep) with Bluetooth disabled. Based on the logs I found this time, my `00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-LP USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 21)` it to blame:

```
kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.004 seconds) done.
kernel: OOM killer disabled.
kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
kernel: pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -16
kernel: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -16
kernel: PM: Device 0000:00:14.0 failed to suspend async: error -16
kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
kernel: rtc_cmos 00:01: Alarms can be up to one month in the future
kernel: OOM killer enabled.
kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
kernel: [drm] RC6 on
kernel: thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
kernel: PM: suspend exit
kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
kernel: PM: Syncing filesystems ... done.
kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
kernel: OOM killer disabled.
kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.056 seconds) done.
kernel: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
kernel: pci_pm_suspend(): hcd_pci_suspend+0x0/0x30 returns -16
kernel: dpm_run_callback(): pci_pm_suspend+0x0/0x150 returns -16
kernel: PM: Device 0000:00:14.0 failed to suspend async: error -16
kernel: PM: Some devices failed to suspend, or early wake event detected
kernel: rtc_cmos 00:01: Alarms can be up to one month in the future
kernel: OOM killer enabled.
kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
kernel: [drm] RC6 on
kernel: thermal thermal_zone8: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
systemd[1]: Failed to start Suspend.
```

Answer (score 3):

My laptop which used to suspend OK most of the time started having problems last week. Perhaps due to a faulty cable. I created a bash script which suspends and resumes faster than before and more reliably.

Use this command:

```bash
sudo -H gedit /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd
```

Copy and paste the following into the editor:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Original script was using /bin/sh but shellcheck reporting warnings.

# NAME: custom-xhci_hcd
# PATH: /lib/systemd/system-sleep
# CALL: Called from SystemD automatically
# DESC: Suspend broken for USB3.0 as of Oct 25/2018 various kernels all at once

# DATE: Oct 28 2018.

# NOTE: From comment #61 at: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/522998

TMPLIST=/tmp/xhci-dev-list

# Original script was: case "${1}" in hibernate|suspend)

case $1/$2 in
  pre/*)
    echo "$0: Going to $2..."
    echo -n '' > $TMPLIST
          for i in `ls /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/ | egrep '[0-9a-z]+\:[0-9a-z]+\:.*$'`; do
              # Unbind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
               echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/unbind
           echo "$i" >> $TMPLIST
          done
        ;;
  post/*)
    echo "$0: Waking up from $2..."
    for i in `cat $TMPLIST`; do
              # Bind xhci_hcd for first device XXXX:XX:XX.X:
              echo -n "$i" | tee /sys/bus/pci/drivers/xhci_hcd/bind
    done
    rm $TMPLIST
        ;;
esac
```

Then save the file and exit `gedit`.

Mark the script as executable using:

```bash
sudo chmod a+x /lib/systemd/system-sleep/custom-xhci_hcd
```

Now your suspend/resume problems should go away. If not hopefully someone else posts their solution.

Comment: This worked great, but removing the `echo "$0:...` from each block seemed to help (I was seeing the `echo`ed result when my screen woke and seeing odd behavior sometimes). Thanks for posting WinEunuuchs2Unix!

Comment: Also worked for me, with a Samsung NP700z5B-s-1ub (for search reference!). Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, works for Dell Precision 5550 on Pop OS 21.04 . Suspend broke when bluetooth was enabled and this solution fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

Could be kernel bug [200039](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=200039). Removing the `btusb` module would help in that case (`rmmod btusb`). If that is the case you could indeed load/unload the kernel module via a sleep script, much as the one posted here.

Comment: I think `btusb` was built-in when I last tried it.

Comment: @christian-kellner Is there a "undo" command for "rmmod btusb"?