# Suspend fails to resume on Dell XPS 15 7590 on battery power only

Tags: suspend, dell, 19.04, battery, xps

I set my Dell XPS 7590 to use deep suspend, and it works fine when the laptop is plugged in to AC power, but fails on battery power.

When attempting to suspend and resume on battery, the syslog shows that everything stops after the `PM: suspend entry (deep)` entry. When I attempt to resume, I can hear the fans spinning, but the system is unresponsive, screen doesn't turn on, and I end up having to power cycle the system.

I've tried setting `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="nouveau.blacklist=1 acpi_rev_override=1 acpi_osi=Linux nouveau.modeset=0 pcie_aspm=force drm.vblankoffdelay=1 scsi_mod.use_blk_mq=1 nouveau.runpm=0 mem_sleep_default=deep"` and upgraded to kernel version `5.2.15-050215-generic` to see if that would solve the problem, but it's still happening. I've also tried disabling `tlp` and manually setting it to `ac` mode with no success. I also made sure I'm running the latest BIOS version from Dell.

Here's the syslog for suspend on battery:

```
Sep 18 19:51:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1734]: <info>  [1568857860.3712] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Sep 18 19:51:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1734]: <info>  [1568857860.3714] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 18 19:51:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1734]: <info>  [1568857860.3727] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Sep 18 19:51:00 XPS-15-7590 whoopsie[2521]: [19:51:00] offline
Sep 18 19:51:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
Sep 18 19:51:01 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Sep 18 19:51:01 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 18 19:51:01 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Sep 18 19:51:01 XPS-15-7590 systemd-sleep[12704]: Suspending system...
Sep 18 19:51:01 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [  364.809262] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

And here it is when the system properly suspends on AC:

```
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1759]: <info>  [1568910060.0713] manager: sleep: sleep requested (sleeping: no  enabled: yes)
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1759]: <info>  [1568910060.0714] device (p2p-dev-wlp59s0): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'sleeping', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1759]: <info>  [1568910060.0728] manager: NetworkManager state is now ASLEEP
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 whoopsie[2644]: [10:21:00] offline
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting TLP suspend/resume...
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started TLP suspend/resume.
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 systemd-sleep[18192]: Suspending system...
Sep 19 10:21:00 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.839101] PM: suspend entry (deep)
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.851184] Filesystems sync: 0.012 seconds
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.852021] Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.853863] OOM killer disabled.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.853863] Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.001 seconds) done.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.855535] printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1901.958973] wlp59s0: deauthenticating from 60:a4:4c:f1:94:6c by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1902.162201] psmouse serio1: Failed to disable mouse on isa0060/serio1
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.380930] ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.479259] ACPI: Preparing to enter system sleep state S3
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.487990] ACPI: EC: event blocked
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.487991] ACPI: EC: EC stopped
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.487991] PM: Saving platform NVS memory
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.488052] Disabling non-boot CPUs ...
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.489390] smpboot: CPU 1 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.492691] smpboot: CPU 2 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.494867] IRQ 169: no longer affine to CPU3
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.495870] smpboot: CPU 3 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.498090] IRQ 174: no longer affine to CPU4
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.499356] smpboot: CPU 4 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.502670] smpboot: CPU 5 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.506200] smpboot: CPU 6 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.508457] IRQ 123: no longer affine to CPU7
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.508459] IRQ 125: no longer affine to CPU7
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.508465] IRQ 151: no longer affine to CPU7
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.509471] smpboot: CPU 7 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.511727] IRQ 128: no longer affine to CPU8
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.511730] IRQ 131: no longer affine to CPU8
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.511737] IRQ 177: no longer affine to CPU8
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.512735] smpboot: CPU 8 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.515182] IRQ 130: no longer affine to CPU9
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.516187] smpboot: CPU 9 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.518412] IRQ 122: no longer affine to CPU10
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.519429] smpboot: CPU 10 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.522821] smpboot: CPU 11 is now offline
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.528860] ACPI: Low-level resume complete
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.528956] ACPI: EC: EC started
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.528956] PM: Restoring platform NVS memory
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.537390] Enabling non-boot CPUs ...
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.537420] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.537421] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 1 APIC 0x2
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.540304] intel_pstate: Disabling energy efficiency optimization
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.540426] CPU1 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.540447] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 2 APIC 0x4
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.541061] CPU2 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.541080] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 3 APIC 0x6
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.541674] CPU3 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.541692] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 4 APIC 0x8
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.542301] CPU4 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.542317] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 5 APIC 0xa
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.542951] CPU5 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.542968] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 6 APIC 0x1
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.543819] CPU6 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.543841] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 7 APIC 0x3
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.544486] CPU7 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.544506] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 8 APIC 0x5
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.545169] CPU8 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.545185] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 9 APIC 0x7
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.545860] CPU9 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.545877] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 10 APIC 0x9
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.546565] CPU10 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.546582] smpboot: Booting Node 0 Processor 11 APIC 0xb
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.547357] CPU11 is up
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.556657] ACPI: Waking up from system sleep state S3
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1903.980386] ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.021038] ACPI: EC: event unblocked
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.022642] usb usb3: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.022644] usb usb4: root hub lost power or was reset
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.033511] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.131450] nvme nvme0: Shutdown timeout set to 8 seconds
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.144805] nvme nvme0: 12/0/0 default/read/poll queues
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.187755] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.263197] usb 1-1: reset full-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.342802] ata3: SATA link down (SStatus 4 SControl 300)
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.543194] usb 1-12: reset high-speed USB device number 6 using xhci_hcd
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.714958] acpi LNXPOWER:08: Turning OFF
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.715005] acpi LNXPOWER:02: Turning OFF
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.715030] acpi LNXPOWER:01: Turning OFF
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.715056] OOM killer enabled.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.715056] Restarting tasks ... done.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 wpa_supplicant[1760]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-SIGNAL-CHANGE above=0 signal=0 noise=9999 txrate=0
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 wpa_supplicant[1760]: wlp59s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=60:a4:4c:f1:94:6c reason=3 locally_generated=1
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1759]: <warn>  [1568910070.1907] sup-iface[0x55f9934e8130,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Starting Daily apt download activities...
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 NetworkManager[1759]: <info>  [1568910070.1962] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: completed -> disconnected
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd-sleep[18192]: System resumed.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 kernel: [ 1904.787032] PM: suspend exit
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Started Suspend.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Stopping TLP suspend/resume...
Sep 19 10:21:10 XPS-15-7590 systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it ended up being Bluetooth that was causing these issues, but it was preventing resume rather than keeping the system awake. I ended up following the instructions here and things appear to be working correctly now.

[Wakes from suspend immediately when bluetooth device disconnected](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1089067/wakes-from-suspend-immediately-when-bluetooth-device-disconnected/1092933)